# what would be best for this operation ,asynctask or thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I know what is asynctask and thread,but I wonder what would be best and fast to use for this kind of operation? -
So basically - I have activity with google map and it keep updating location every time , and I  have many polygons that need to be check if the current location is in those polygons , and I wonder what should I do?

1) create a thread that basically keeps checking if the current location is in those polygons.

2) create asynctask from my main thread each time the location have changed and check the current location in those polygons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ofcourse use AsyncTask

Comment: Use service with brodcast reciver  it would be best in your case.

Comment: if takes alot of time i should change it to thread instead?

Comment: suhas the operations are simple to be processed i think using a service would make it harder to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, `AsyncTask`s and thread are identical. Internally `AsyncTask` uses Java thread to spawn a background thread. However, using `Service` is different.

Threads and `AsyncTask`s are run in context of the component that start them. But, Services provide their own context.

For example, you can achieve the same functionality as an `AsyncTask` does provide by this code snippet.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); // Here is main / UI thread.
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        /* Background tasks go here */

        /* Once you're done ...*/
        handler.post(new Runable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                /* Post-execution code go here */
            }
        })
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: sweet , basically i wanted to post notifaction in the UI,  if the  current location is in one of the polygen  i think this example should help thanks alot